# Browser's screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution

I have:

```
window.addEventListener('resize',doSomething,false);
        function doSomething() {
            var yres = document.body.offsetHeight;
            var xres = document.body.offsetWidth;
            alert(xres+'x'+yres);
        }
```

This function shows my body resolution in google chrome my (1350x651), in firefox (1509x20) and in internet explorer (nothing).  Why are the resolution from different browser different?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery it's simple, do something like:

```
$(window).width();
$(document).width();
$(window).height();
$(document).height();
```

Without js this should suffice:

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

In your case im guessing you would use window since that's where you added the listener. Also, http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm could help with some more foolproof code since offsetWidth and Height seems to be some IE thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`

Comment: @drake Maybe because your browser windows are of different size? What exactly do you need? The size of the screen, the size of the browser window (inner, or outer), or the size of your "body" element?